# Enable When Checkbox is Check in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I need help in making the rows enable only when the checkbox is check. The default rows should be disabled but when the checkbox is only check, that row will be enabled. Here's the link to my code

[LINK CODES](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unckmj?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
  patchValues() {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    this.orders.forEach(material => {
      material.materials.forEach(x => {
      rows.push(this.fb.group({
        checkbox_value: [null],
        material_id:  new FormControl({value: x.id, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        material_name: x.name, 
        quantity: [null, Validators.required]
      }))
    })
      })

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Have a look at the Demo & Src

[Stack Blitz, Fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/enable-when-checkbox-is-check-in-reactive-forms-cchhs2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

> Explanation:

1. For enabling or disabling a input field, you need to use the following syntax `[attr.disabled]="myForm.get('rows').value[i].checkbox_value ? null: ''"`
2. `attr.disabled`, here attr is for binding with properties which don't exist directly on an element
3. `myForm.get('rows').value[i].checkbox_value`, is fairly straight forward access to a form control's value.

Comment: Hi Abhijit Kar. I have putted a submit button and I need to save only those who have checkbox. So if a td has a checkbox, qty field should be inputted. Here's the forked link https://stackblitz.com/edit/enable-when-checkbox-is-check-in-reactive-forms-q1drqd?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @Joseph, have a look at the fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/enable-when-checkbox-is-check-in-reactive-forms-cchhs2. You just handle the submission in onCreateProduct() method.

Comment: I'm sorry. The button "save" should be enabled too. That's my problem.

Comment: @Joseph have a look now

Comment: Sorry I've to bother again. I saw one problem. When i click the checkbox and i input something in the quantity field and then uncheck the checkbox, i can still click the save button. It doesn't disabled.

Comment: @Joseph, because the input fields have values. Let me clear them as well.

Comment: Ok ill just wait. Thanks :)

Comment: @Joseph, I have added a function to check, if any of the checkbox is checked. If yes, then only save button is enabled

Comment: My angular app is becomes unresponsive when i did this? But your plunker is working well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166612/discussion-between-abhijit-kar-and-joseph).

Answer (score 2):

Another aproach is create a directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[enabledControl]'
})
export class EnabledControlDirective {

    @Input() set enabledControl(condition: boolean) {
        if (this.ngControl) {
            if (this.ngControl.control) {
                if (condition)
                    this.ngControl.control.enable();
                else
                    this.ngControl.control.disable();
            }
        }
  }
  constructor(private ngControl : NgControl ) {
  }
}
```

Then you can use like

```
<input class="col-md-6" formControlName="quantity"
     [enabledControl]="row.get('checkbox_value').value" >
```