# how to disable a form element of formArray in reactive formGroup using Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am having two dropdown in an formArray.

```
<select formControlName="access" (change)="checkValue($event)" >
  <option[value]="1">Admin</option>
  <option[value]="2">Customer</option>
</select>

<mat-select  formControlName="regions" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let region of regionArray" [value]="region.regionId">{{region.description}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I am disabling the regions selection if the access selected is as Admin.

```
checkValue(event) {  
    if (event.currentTarget.value === "1") {
        return this.myForm = this.fb.group({
                user: this.fb.array([this.disableDetail(),   ])
            }); 
    } else {  
        return this.myForm = this.fb.group({
                user: this.fb.array([this.enableDetail(),    ])
            }); 
    } 
}

enableDetail() {    
    return this.fb.group({
        regions: [{value:'',Validators: Validators.required, disabled:false}]     });   
    }

disableDetail() {
    return this.fb.group({
        regions: [{value:'', disabled:true}]    });  
}
```

I am facing issue that it is affecting the other form array.
 I want if the dropdown value  I am choosing as Admin it should disable and select all values of region dropdown only for that particular formarray.

Comment: new FormGroup({
                'regions': new FormControl({value:null,disabled: true}, Validators.required)
            })

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<select formControlName="access" (change)="checkValue($event)" >
  <option[value]="1">Admin</option>
  <option[value]="2">Customer</option>
</select>

<mat-select [disabled]="isAdmin" formControlName="regions" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let region of regionArray" [value]="region.regionId">{{region.description}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Component**

```
isAdmin: boolean;
checkValue(event) {  
    this.isAdmin = event.currentTarget.value === "1";
}
```

Comment: I don't know mat-select, but you can take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205601/enable-when-checkbox-is-check-in-reactive-forms